# How to grep number of occurence of two different words in a file on Linux?

Tags: grep

How to grep number of occurrence of two different words e.g. 'register' and 'evn' in a file on Linux ?

The output should be like following:

```
registered:20
```

Comment: You should clarify the requirements. 1) Multiple occurrences of a word on the same line should be counted as 1 (as in [McNisse's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60738)) or should count each (as in [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60739))? 2) All words with the same base should be counted (as in [dchirikov's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60729)) or only exact matches (as in [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60739)).

Answer (score 5):

In case reversed output format (count first, word after) is also acceptable, this does it too and is easy to add more words:

```
tr -c '[:alpha:]' '\n' < /path/to/file | sort | uniq -c | grep -w 'register\|evn'
```

- Counts each word occurrence, even if there are multiple occurrences in the same line.
- Counts exact matches of the words, not including the suffixed variants.

Answer (score 4):

Use `awk`

```
awk '/register/ {r++} /evn/ {e++} END {printf("register:%d\nevn:%d\n", r, e)}' /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate it separately:

```
$ word=register; count=`grep -o $word /path/to/file| wc -l`; echo $word:$count
$ word=evn; count=`grep -o $word /path/to/file| wc -l`; echo $word:$count
```

Comment: You don't need to `wc -l`. `grep -c` gives the count directly.

Comment: @McNisse Actually, you do because grep will only count line occurrences and there may be more than one occurrence of a word in a line.

Answer (score 1):

**example file** `./filename`**:**

```
registering evn register evn
evn register evn.register. register.evn evn evn register. 
evn register-evnt register
```

**command:**

```
echo register:$(grep -oP "(^|\s)\Kregister(?=\s|$)|(^|\s)\Kregister\.(?=\s|$)" ./filename | wc -l) && echo evn:$(grep -oP '(^|\s)\Kevn(?=\s|$)|(^|\s)\Kevn\.(?=\s|$)' ./filename | wc -l)
```

**example output:**

```
register:4
evn:6
```

This should accurately count only the words "register" and "evn" while omitting occurrences of words containing "register" and or "evn" such as "registering", "evnt", or "register-evn" for example.

This assumes that there are no special characters like dashes immediately following either word but *will* include these words if they are followed by a period at the end of a line or sentence.

[This linked answer gave me the info I needed for the grep syntax.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206911/70847)

Answer (score -1):

```
word="registered"
echo $word:$( grep -wc $word /path/to/file )
```

Works with Bash/Ksh and GNU grep