# Match exact string using grep

Tags: grep

I have a text file:

```
deiauk 1611516 afsdf 765
minkra 18415151 asdsf 4152
linkra sfsfdsfs sdfss 4555
deiauk1 sdfsfdsfs 1561 51
deiauk2 115151 5454 4
deiauk 1611516 afsdf ddfgfgd
luktol1 4545 4 9
luktol 1
```

and I want to match exactly `deiauk`.  When I do this:

```
grep "deiauk" file.txt
```

I get this result:

```
deiauk 1611516 afsdf 765
deiauk1 sdfsfdsfs 1561 51
deiauk2 115151 5454 4
```

but I only need this:

```
deiauk 1611516 afsdf 765
deiauk 1611516 afsdf ddfgfgd
```

I know there's a `-w` option, but then my string has to mach whole line.

Comment: Have you actually tried `grep -w`? (That option is exactly for that purpose, and it works for me.) - Note: option `-x` matches the whole line.

Comment: *"I want to match exactly `deiauk`* / *"I only need this: `deiauk 1611516 afsdf 765`"* - which do you need?

Answer (score 230, accepted):

Try one of:

```
grep -w "deiauk" textfile

grep "\<deiauk\>" textfile
```

Comment: If you have a dash (**-**) at the end of the string this script will bring it as a result, which was not expected.

Comment: Correct @Evert : Words include only alpha chars, digits and underscores, so if you have abbreviations or other items hyphenated, this does not work.

Comment: @Cyrus I learnt the second one while using vi/vim `*` command on words.

Comment: It does not work for any special character it have for example `org.apache.avro avro` greped with `org.apache.avro avro+mapred` (tried with *)

Comment: [Use `-wE`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/479029/209677) for exact match of multiple words (boolean OR)

Comment: @Evis Use `grep -w "deiauk$" textfile` instead.

Comment: Thank you @Evis! This is the only solution that works for my problem where I am searching for "skygrid_20-35/mosaics/field_14" and want  to exclude "skygrid_20-35/mosaics/field_14.1"

Comment: @Janis is the second option a gnu feature? That is not working for me in AIX.

Comment: first option worked fine for me.

Answer (score 27):

Try this with GNU `grep` and mark word boundaries with `\b`:

```
grep "\bdeiauk\b" file
```

Output:

```
deiauk 1611516 afsdf 765
```

See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: Thanks but why this is not working for me?
`echo "Enter login: " $vard`

`grep -E "$\bvard\b" file.txt`

Comment: Try `grep "\b${vard}\b" file.txt`

Comment: still doesn't work :/

Comment: You'll need `read`: `read -p "Enter login: " vard; grep "\b${vard}\b" file.txt`

Answer (score 16):

If your `grep` supports `-P` (PCRE), you can do:

```
$ grep -P '(^|\s)\Kdeiauk(?=\s|$)' file.txt 
deiauk 1611516 afsdf 765
deiauk 1611516 afsdf ddfgfgd
```

Comment: This is the only answer that works with hyphenated words.

Comment: Why is `\K` (PCRE reset start of match) needed? This proposed solution seems to work just fine without it.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on your real data, you could look for the word followed by a space:

```
grep 'deiauk ' file.txt
```

If you know it has to be at the start of the line, check for it:

```
grep '^deiauk ' file.txt
```

Comment: Sadly, all of the answers other than this are incorrect.

Comment: @Shatu Thanks! So let's see how long it takes for it to "bubble up to the top"... I'm curious because I like to add answers to old questions... I think it is assumed it does, but I doubt it. It would be just nice for me, but actually useful for the readers. To make this a good example case, could I ask you to write a comment summarizing what the other answers are missing?

Comment: (1) Congratulations on reaching 10K rep. You now have the privilege to see that this answer was given before, and was deleted. (2) It’s always better to answer the question as broadly as possible, based on *what is said,* and not give an answer that works just for the sample data. It appears, from the example data in the question, that the columns are separated by spaces — but that’s not specified. All the other answers will also work for tab-separated columns. (3) You avoided the fatal flaw in tachomi’s (deleted) answer by adding the `^` — but all the other answers work … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  if the string appears in a field other than the first one.  (4) Also, all the other answers work if ‘‘deiauk’’ is the last field (i.e., there’s nothing after it).

Comment: This answer is not only correct but also readable. And probably the most portable across platforms.

Answer (score 4):

I found `-x` worked for me.

Example

```
$ grep -inx -d skip 'favicon.ico' *
test.txt:1:favicon.ico
```

Grep Manual

```
-x, --line-regexp
              Select  only  those  matches  that  exactly  match the whole line.  For a regular expression pattern, this is like
              parenthesizing the pattern and then surrounding it with ^ and $.
```

Comment: For 1:1 matching the whole line which contains hyphens, ``-x`` the only option.
For example ``grep -w "abc" <<<"abc-hac101-bb0"`` will match but ``grep -x "abc" <<<"abc-hac101-bb0"`` will not

Comment: -1 `grep -x` searches for the entire line, so `grep -x deiauk` will not pick up the required line `deiauk 1611516 afsdf 765` only grep -x 'deiauk 1611516 afsdf 765' will do that. The original question was "and I want to match exactly deiauk" which you have not done.