# exact string matching for multiple strings with grep

Tags: grep, string

I am looking for exact string matches for multiple strings using grep.

Lets say I want to find the following three strings in a large data file that has about 10 Million rows and 10 columns.  I want to query the file so I find all the rows that have the following exact strings in them.  Thankfully only 1 column has 'rs numbers' so I don't need to specify the column:
rs123
rs246
rs689653

I tried the following expression and am returned all options that have these strings in them.  In some cases, I'll see rows that have something like 'rs123456', where as I just want rows with the exact matches:

```
grep -E 'rs123|rs246|rs689653' queriedfile.txt
```

Then I tried the following expression with `^` and `$` but received back NO matches to my query (and I know there are some).

```
grep -E '^rs123$|^rs246$|^rs689653$' queriedfile.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the `-w` command line option to restrict the match to whole words

```
$ printf 'rs123456\nrs246\n' | grep -wE 'rs123|rs246|rs689653'
rs246
```

or add word-anchors explicitly

```
$ printf 'rs123456\nrs246\n' | grep -E '\b(rs123|rs246|rs689653)\b'
rs246
```

(you were close with `^` and `$` - but those are *line*-anchors).

Comment: Will i still be returned the full line that the string is in?  (that's what I want!)

Comment: Actually yes! I will be returned the full line! I just tried it! Thank you!  I did grep -wE 'rs123|rs246|rs689653' ' queriedfile.txt

Answer (score 0):

If you want *exact* string matching:

```
grep -Fwf <(printf "%s\n" rs123 rs246 rs689653) file
```

Where `-F` gives you exact string matching (no regex), `-w` is whole word, and `-f` reads the "patterns" from the file supplied by the process substitution.

If you have more words to match so that the printf part gets quite long, you can use a shell array to hold them:

```
words=( rs123 rs246 rs689653 )
grep -Fwf <(printf "%s\n" "${words[@]}") file
```

---

Alternatively, awk might work for your needs:

```
awk -F '\t' '
    $6 == "rs123"
    $6 == "rs246"
    $6 == "rs689653"
' file
```

Replace your actual field separator and field number as appropriate.