# Grep remove line with 0 but not 0.2?

Tags: grep

I have a file whose content is similar to the following one.

```
0
0
0.2
0
0
0
0
```

I need to remove all the lines with a single zero.
I was thinking to use `grep -v "0"`, but this removes also the line containing 0.2. I saw I could use the `-w` option, but this doesn't seem to work either.

How can I remove all the lines containing just a single 0 and keep all those lines starting with a 0?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Match exact string using grep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206903/match-exact-string-using-grep)

Comment: @JulienLopez It's not a dupe of that question. That question is about matching a word, and answered with `-w`, which fails here.

Comment: Why are you forced to use `grep` for this task? And what exactly do you mean by _a single zero_? This sounds very much like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @RolandIllig it was 1 hour before bedtime and I wanted to start processing a series of 500,000 strings to check if they were bitcoin private keys and if so get balance. Next time I had time to look at it I had processed many thousands of the strings and I just wanted to parse for any non-zero values.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
grep -vx 0
```

From `man grep`:

```
-x, --line-regexp
       Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line.
       For a regular expression pattern, this is like parenthesizing
       the pattern and then surrounding it with ^ and $.
```

`-w` fails because the first `0` in `0.02` is considered a "word", and hence this line is matched. This is because it is followed by a "non-word" character. You can see this if you run the original command without `-v`, i.e. `grep -w "0"`.

Comment: You could also use the `-F` option since we're not using regex patterns, just plain string matching

Comment: @glennjackman Maybe I've read this earlier, but I can't seem to find it now. Running with `-F` (surprisingly to me) appears to take a similar amount of time or even slightly slower (~5–10%). Hence, I'm not sure what the advantage would be.

Comment: It's possible that the RegEx engine is used so often and so widely used that they have implemented a very efficient version of it, but that a "plain search" probably has not been upgraded for 30 years.

Comment: @Sparhawk: `grep` presumably has a special case for regexes with no metacharacters, because that's a common use-case.  It's surprising that `fgrep` would be slower, but it's not surprising that the overhead of noticing this special case while compiling a short pattern is negligible vs. the time to scan a large file.  (If it requires a special case at all to go that fast, vs. a pattern with a character class or `x.*y`.)

Comment: But that's maybe an oversimplification because the input is actually many short lines (not one giant string).  I forget if `grep` recognizes any character other than `\n` newline as a line separator.  If not, the implicit `^` and `$`  can still turn into a fixed-string search like `strstr(big_buf, "\n0\n")`.  (Or `0\n` at the start of a buffer.)  But we're not just looking for the first match potentially far into a big buffer, we want to efficiently filter.  But anyway, in theory yes it's just a 2-byte memcmp at the start of each line, and you'd hope that both fgrep and grep would see that.

Answer (score 30):

With grep:

```
grep -v '^0$' file
```

`^` means beginning of the line, `$` means end of the line.

Comment: This is what the user asked for : avoid any lines containing only 1 "0".

Comment: I would not put a literal dollar sign inside double quotes like that.

Comment: @mehrdad not that big problem with regex as it is usually either last char or next one wont be `[a-Z0-9]`

Answer (score 14):

While `grep` *can* be used for this (as other answers clearly show), let’s take a step back and think about what you actually want:

- You have a file containing *numbers*
- You want to perform filtering based on the *numeric value*.

Regex interpret character sequence data. They don’t know about numbers, only about individual digits (and regular combinations thereof). Although in your particular case there’s a simple hack around this limitation, it’s ultimately a requirement mismatch.

Unless there’s a very good reason to use `grep` here (e.g. because you’ve measured it, and it’s vastly more efficient, and efficiency is crucial in your case), I recommend using a different tool.

`awk`, for instance, can filter based on numeric comparisions, e.g.:

```
awk '$1 == 0' your_file
```

But also, to get all lines containing numbers greater than zero:

```
awk '$1 > 0' your_file
```

I love regex, it’s a great tool. But it’s not the *only* tool. As the saying goes, if all you have is `grep`, everything looks like a regular language.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree that awk may be more elegant here... however, it will also match maybe a little bit more than what the user expects (every numerical value evaluating to 0). Ie, `printf '0\n1\n-1\na\nb\n0\n0 also\n0.0\n-0.0\n0*0\n' | awk '($1 == 0)'` will match: `0`, `0.0` and `-0.0`... and also `0 also` ! Not just "0". (which is sometimes what's needed, sometimes not). If the user want only "0" : `awk '/^0$/'`  (or `grep '^0$'`). Also you should edit: the user needs to add `!` to negate the test, so it hides `0` (and other zeroes) and displays the rest. ie: `awk '!( $0 == 0)'`

Comment: @Olivier, or check the string value: `$1 == "0"`

Comment: @OlivierDulac I explicitly used `>` rather than `!=` (or, equivalently, `! (… == …)`) to highlight that this is an arbitrary numerical comparison, not just equality. As for your other comment, this is entirely true but then we’re essentially back in string comparison territory and the existing solution using `grep` works (though `awk` of course also works).

Comment: @KonradRudolph fair points :)

Comment: @glennjackman: nice trick indeed. But then OP would rather do test `$0=="0"`

Answer (score 6):

`grep`'s `-w` is a bit convoluted in a way that it splits up the original string into word and non-word constituents (anything except letters, digits or underscore) . Since it has already encountered a a valid word constituent `0` in `0.02` it had asserted the negation logic to remove the line.

Using `sed` is a bit easy in this context to just remove the whole words that match

```
sed '/^0$/d' file
```

Answer (score 4):

When the lines you want to delete **only contain** a `0` **followed by the next line** you can select those lines by issuing the following command:

```
grep -v "^0$"
```

This will only print the occurrences of `0` that are *at the end of a line* and *at the beginning of a line* at the same time. The `-v` option then inverts our selection.

Comment: This answer is almost identical to Arkadiusz Drabczyk's, but you forgot the `-v`, so it doesn't work.

Comment: You're right. I was typing while he posted his answer so I didn't see it has already been given. I've misread that part with the `-v` option, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- `\b` - word border

  ```
  grep -v "\b0\b"
  ```
- match beginning of line, your pattern and end of line

  ```
  grep -v "^0$"
  ```
- or as @Sparhawk suggested `-vx` lineregexp

**Note** that `-w` works, but in your case `0.2` are *two words* because dot character is a word separator.

Comment: `grep -v "\b0\b"` doesn't really work here.  What version of grep do you use?

Comment: works with `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD` on macOS and `grep (GNU grep) 2.16` on ubuntu

Comment: GNU regex use `\<` and`\>` as word boundaries, but that will have the same effect as `-w`

Answer (score 0):

Another answer for the sake of variety, assuming you have a PCRE-enabled `grep`

```
grep -Pv "^0(?!\.)"
```

this performs a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match the lines that start with `0` and **are not** followed by a dot. Then `-v` discards non-matching lines. You can see in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/nYuUC9/1)

Comment: This will also remove lines such as `0123`, which is not what the OP wants

Answer (score 0):

Assuming any line which is not just a single 0 has a period

`grep '\.' file`