# Why does grep -x imply parenthesizing the pattern?

Tags: grep

While [answering](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/500550/18887) another question, I quoted `man grep`, in relation to `-x`

```
-x, --line-regexp
       Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line.
       For a regular expression pattern, this is like parenthesizing
       the pattern and then surrounding it with ^ and $.
```

I already knew that `-x` was like "surrounding [the regex] with `^` and `$`", but why does it also imply "parenthesizing the pattern"?

I can't think of why parenthesizing would be necessary, or even change anything. If the whole pattern were parenthesized, you couldn't refer to it internally with a capturing group. `grep` complains about trailing backslashes, so there's no odd behaviour from an appended `)` either (nor would I expect that to be in the spirit of an option).

Why does `man grep` specifically mention `parenthesizing the pattern` for `-x`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One instance where it’s important is for regular expressions with alternatives:

```
grep -E 'this|that'
```

If you only add `^` and `$` without parenthesizing, this becomes

```
grep -E '^this|that$'
```

which matches lines starting with “this” or ending with “that”, rather than lines containing only “this” or “that”.