# Grep output until a matching word before/after

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Hello I need to grep for specific string and I need to print output before/after until a matching word.
Here is an example: The string which I search is dmz (I need exact string match because I have similar strings that contain dmz1 which are not in my interest) and I need to print the whole output that start with "edit"  until "next"

```
=============================
edit 1825
set uuid 1e73dff8-2037-51e7-9713-3539a6b60c4c
set srcintf "dmz" <---
set dstintf "tralalala"
set srcaddr tralalala
set dstaddr tralalala
set action accept
set status disable
set schedule "always"
set service "tralalala"
next
===========================
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please see this thread. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206903/match-exact-string-using-grep

Comment: Do you mean that all lines between `edit` and `next` have to be printed if `dmz` appears between those lines? Also, what do you mean by "exact string"? In my mind, `dmz1` contains the exact string `dmz`. In your mind, it doesn't seem to.

Comment: Are the lines with the equal signs part of the data? Does the next and previous record contain the equal signs, or are they shared? Does the first record start with the equal signs? Could you show a more complete data set? What should happen if there are multiple records containing the word `dmz`? What happens if a record contains the word `dmz` elsewhere and not with a `set srcintf` at the start of the line (like `set service "dmz"`)?