# Counting occurrences of word in text file

Tags: text-processing, grep, cut

I have a text file containing tweets and I'm required to count the number of times a word is mentioned in the tweet. For example, the file contains:

```
Apple iPhone X is going to worth a fortune
The iPhone X is Apple's latest flagship iPhone. How will it pit against it's competitors?
```

And let's say I want to count how many times the word iPhone is mentioned in the file. So here's what I've tried.

```
cut -f 1 Tweet_Data | grep -i "iPhone" | wc -l
```

it certainly works but I'm confused about the 'wc' command in unix. What is the difference if I try something like:

```
cut -f 1 Tweet_Data | grep -c "iPhone"
```

where -c is used instead? Both of these yield different results in a large file full of tweets and I'm confused on how it works. Which method is the correct way of counting the occurrence?

Comment: `cut -f1` is cutting based on tabs, which isn't doing much here. Are you sure that `wc -l` is really giving you the correct count? It would show 2 here, but I count 3 instances of "iPhone".

Comment: Another technique: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/39039/117549

Comment: Also similar: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/60727/117549

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count total number of occurrences using grep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6979/count-total-number-of-occurrences-using-grep)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Given such a requirement, I would use a GNU grep (for the [`-o` option](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)), *then* pass it through `wc` to count the total number of occurrences:

```
$ grep -o -i iphone Tweet_Data | wc -l
3
```

Plain `grep -c` on the data will count the number of *lines* that match, not the total number of *words* that match. Using the `-o` option tells grep to output each match on its own line, no matter how many times the match was found in the original line.

`wc -l` tells the `wc` utility to count the number of lines. After grep puts each match in its own line, this is the total number of occurrences of the word in the input.

---

If GNU grep is not available (or desired), you could transform the input with `tr` so that each word is on its own line, then use `grep -c` to count:

```
$ tr '[:space:]' '[\n*]' < Tweet_Data | grep -i -c iphone
3
```

Comment: `-o` option is also available in MacOS/BSD `grep`

Answer (score 7):

Easiest Method is,

```
grep -wc "your_text" FileName
```

for you it wil be,

```
grep -wc "iPhone" Tweet_Data
```

Comment: Very clean answer however if you are matching a word like 'cool' you will only match cool and NOT ccooll so be aware that spaces around the word matter.

Comment: The result will be incorrect when the word occurs more than once in a line.