# move files that contain a pattern a certain number of times

Tags: files, file-copy

I have many files (with a `.fna` extension). I need to move them, if they contain the character **>** a certain number of times.

I know which files contain **>** a certain number of times (9 times in this example) with this command.

```
grep -c ">" *.fna | grep ":9"
```

Which gives an output like this

```
5242_ref.fna:9
9418_ref.fna:9
```

But I don't know how to move those files to another folder.

Thanks.

Comment: If a line contains two symbols (`>>`), does it count only once (as `grep -c` would do), or twice (as "contains > a certain number of times" would do?

Comment: counts as twice

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly. You might update your Q to remove the misleading "grep" output as what you intend is different -- grep counts matching *lines*, not matching bytes.

Comment: Relating only (for the grep occurrence vs line background): https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/398413/117549

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use zsh with its [expression-as-a-glob-qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to select files that only have nine such symbols:

```
$ hasnine() { [[ $(tr -dc '>' < "$REPLY" | wc -c) -eq 9 ]]; }
$ mv *.fna(+hasnine) location/
```

The first line defines a function whose purpose is to create a true/false filter for files that have nine `>` symbols in them. The `tr` command acts on its input, expected in the `REPLY` variable, deleting anything that is not a `>`, then asks `wc` to count the number of resulting characters, and then compares that output to 9.

The second line executes the `mv` command for matching *.fna files to the (example) `location` directory. Matching *.fna files also have to pass the expression qualifier, which is given as the name of the function we defined.

Answer (score 2):

By combining `egrep` (called with the `-l` option so that positive matches return only filenames) with [`xargs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) you can perform arbitrary commands based on text matches:

```bsh
[gnubeard@mothership: ~/mver]$ ls
destination  example.fna  non_example.fna
[gnubeard@mothership: ~/mver]$ cat example.fna
>>>>>>>>>
[gnubeard@mothership: ~/mver]$ cat non_example.fna
<<<<<<<<<
>>
[gnubeard@mothership: ~/mver]$ egrep -l '>{9}' *.fna | xargs -I{} mv {} destination/
[gnubeard@mothership: ~/mver]$ ls
destination  non_example.fna
[gnubeard@mothership: ~/mver]$ ls destination/
example.fna
```

Edit: This doesn't match files with a certain number of instances of a character, if they're separated by other characters or newlines. I've created this short script that should operate as desired.

```bsh
#! /usr/bin/env bash

DESTINATION=./destination
MATCH_CHAR='>'
MATCH_COUNT=9

for FILE in $1; do
  MATCHES=$(grep -o $MATCH_CHAR $FILE | wc -l)
  if [ $MATCHES -eq $MATCH_COUNT ]; then
    mv $FILE $DESTINATION
  fi
done
```

Example:

```
[gnubeard@mothership: ~/mver]$ ls
destination  example.fna  mver  non_example.fna
[gnubeard@mothership: ~/mver]$ cat example.fna
>>
>>foo>>bar>>>baz
[gnubeard@mothership: ~/mver]$ cat non_example.fna
<<<<<<<<<
>>
[gnubeard@mothership: ~/mver]$ ./mver *.fna
[gnubeard@mothership: ~/mver]$ ls destination/
example.fna
[gnubeard@mothership: ~/mver]$ ls
destination  mver  non_example.fna
```

Comment: liked the egrep solution. however, as it is it searchs for >>>>>>>>> and I need to move files with > 9 times not necessarily grouped, but anywhere in the file. what can I do?

Comment: This does answer the question as stated. However there is the bug that @JeffSchaller found. Time for another question.

Comment: I've updated with a solution that'll work regardless of separating characters/newlines.