# Get count of occurrences of each word in document

Tags: shell, pipe, macos, fish

How can I find count of every word in a file?

I want a histogram of each word in text pipe or document. New line and empty lines will exist in document. I stripped everything except for `[a-zA-Z]`.

```
> cat doc.txt 
word second third 

word really
> cat doc.txt | ... # then count occurrences of each word \
                    # and print in descending order separated by delimiter
word 2
really 1
second 1
third 1
```

It needs to be somewhat efficient as file is 1GB text and cannot work with exponential time load.

Comment: Does https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/398413/117549 help?

Comment: Do you really want a fish-specific answer? I'd use perl

Comment: @glennjackman perl is perfectly fine. fish is there to make sure it work on fish and isn't just bash/zsh specific answer as those aren't that useful for me

Comment: Is `Unix-system` one word or two? What about `GNU/Linux`?

Comment: @Kusalananda like I said only `[a-zA-Z]` so hypen cannot exist; only letters small and capital case :) What about GNU/Linux. I chose to tag macOS because I want to make sure that people assume macOS flavor of tools and only expect macOS default tools to exist (installing a separate tool is overkill imo).

Comment: @user14492 Ah, I missed the bit where you deleted all non-letters. By `GNU/Linux` I meant to ask whether it was to be counted as one or two words, but by deleting the non-letter `/` it's clear that it's a single word.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
grep -o '\w*' doc.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

- `-o` Print each match instead of matching lines
- `\w*` Match word characters
- `sort` sort the matches before piping to `uniq`.
- `uniq -c` print the uniqe lines and the number of occurences `-c`
- `sort -nr` Reverse sort by number of occurences.

Output:

```
  2 word
  1 third
  1 second
  1 really
```

---

**Alternative**:

Use `awk` for the exact output:

```
$ grep -o '\w*' doc.txt \
| awk '{seen[$0]++} END{for(s in seen){print s,seen[s]}}' \
| sort -k2r

word 2
really 1
second 1
third 1
```

Comment: With GNU awk, don't need external sort: `END {PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"; for (s in seen) print s, seen[s]}`

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lnE '
  $count{$_}++ for /[[:alpha:]]+/g;
  END {
    say "@$_" for
      sort {$b->[1] <=> $a->[1] || $a->[0] cmp $b->[0]}
      map {[$_, $count{$_}]}
      keys %count
  }
' doc.txt
```

This will consume lots more memory than pLumo's initial solution.